# How to get all sources for imported files with TypeScript compiler API?

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I am trying to parse the AST of a TypeScript program using ts API. I have no trouble creating the program and getting the AST, but strangely, not all imported modules are accessible.

Considering the following file structure with `a.tsx` being my entry point:

```
.
├── a.tsx
├── b
│   └── index.tsx
└── c.tsx
```

If I import a module with its complete filename (extension excluded), it works properly:

```
import { c } from './c';
// or
import { b } from './b/index';
```

But on the `b` module case, if I remove the `index` part (which is a totally valid and working syntax), the module disappears from the program sources.

```
import { b } from './b';
```

The code that creates the program and parse the AST is the following:

```
import * as ts from 'typescript';

const options: ts.CompilerOptions = {
    target: ts.ScriptTarget.ES2015,
    jsx: ts.JsxEmit.Preserve,
};

const program = ts.createProgram([process.argv[2]], options);
const sources = program.getSourceFiles();

sources.forEach((source: ts.SourceFile) => {
    const path_ = source.fileName;
    if (path_.indexOf('node_modules') === -1) {
        console.log(`parsing ${path_}`);
    }
});
```

The sources are returned by `program.getSources()` call.
When `a.tsx` file imports the modules like on my first snippet, I can access all three nodes in the sources, but if I am using the second form (`import .. from './b'`), then sources only contains nodes for modules `a` and `c`.

Is there some specific option to pass `createProgram()` for that?

TypeScript version is 2.4.2.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: ts.preProcessFile is the solution, don't have time to elaborate sorry